# External script execution in Lightbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to call an external script from within a lightbox (prettyPhoto).
Basically the script calls a video from a streaming server.

I'm able to see the lightbox appear, the script begins execution and then immediately causes the page to crash and hang.

Is there a lightbox able to accomplish this? My code looks like this:

```
<a href="#inline-1" rel="prettyPhoto" >Click Here</a>
<div id="inline-1" class="hide">
    <p>This is inline content opened in prettyPhoto.</p>
    <p><script type="text/javascript" src="http://foo.com/example-script.js"></script></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant understand what you are trying to do! BTW you do know there is no code here: http://content.bitsontherun.com/players/foo-bar.js

Comment: Thanks Trufa - I've updated the link.
If you execute the script alone it calls a video. What I'm trying to do is have that video play in the prettyPhoto lightbox. Right now the lighbox appears with the content for a split second then crashes the page.